# Не обновляется связь при переопределении метода save()

Tags: django, model, save

Переопределяю метод save, сохраняю все изменения и вызываю функцию `save_pdf()`(записывает все данные в pdf).

models.py

```
class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    person = models.ManyToManyField(Person, verbose_name = "Люди")
    phone = models.CharField('Номер телефона', max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        save_pdf()
```

С полем phone все отлично, при каждом сохранении он изменяется и в pdf файле. А вот со связью m2m беда. Поле не обновляется при вызове функции `save_pdf()`, остается старое значение.

`save_pdf()`

```
people = Person.objects.All()
for k, person in enumerate(people):
    for phone in person.phonenumber_set.filter(person=person):
        phones = phones + str(phone)+', '
    fio = Paragraph(str(person.name), styleBH)
    table_data.append([fio, phones])
```

Код в `save_pdf()` получился объемный, поэтому скидываю основную часть. Используется reportlab. Перебираю пользователей и их телефоны. Потом тупо записываю все в файл.

Comment: покажите функцию `save_pdf`

Comment: @IvanSemochkin, добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему с помощью `m2m_changed`

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=PhoneNumber.person.through)
@receiver(post_save, sender=PhoneNumber)
def generate_phonenumber_pdf(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     action = kwargs.pop('action', None)
     if(instance.was_phone!=instance.phone or action=='post_add'):
         save_pdf()
```